# Docker ENTRYPOINT shell form with parameters

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I have a Docker image with the following line (a Spring Boot microservice):

```
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher"]
```

I can start the container using e.g.:

```
docker run --rm my_image:1.0.0 --spring.profiles.active=local
```

and it works, the parameter `--spring.profiles.active=local` is used. However, when the shell form of ENTRYPOINT is used:

```
ENTRYPOINT java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher
```

this doesn't work any more, the parameters are ignored. I believe the parameters are passed to the `/bin/sh -c` that is what is used by the shell form.

So how do I pass arguments to the app I want to start when using the shell form?

Comment: Add `"$@"` if you want your shell to look at extra parameters, possibly `"$0" "$@"` depending on implementation details (particularly, whether Docker passes a stub `$0` value in when it's automatically invoking a shell -- if it doesn't you'll see the first extra argument being ignored when you use only `"$@"` but subsequent ones still working). `ENTRYPOINT java org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher "$@"`, then.

Comment: Just use the first form (json). Its almost always the better form to use.

Comment: ...but _really_, TheFool is right. Don't use a shell when you have no good reason for one. (Using this form also means you can't change your base image to be one that doesn't provide `/bin/sh` at all)

Comment: @charlesduffy will `"$@"` work? The docs state: `The shell form prevents any CMD or run command line arguments from being used`

Comment: @Foo, worth testing, then. There's a good chance that the folks writing the docs (or even the implementation) didn't know that `"$@"` _could_ be used and that it works just fine, but I won't claim to know with certainty either way; depends on whether Docker still passes content through when the shell form is used.

Comment: (if Docker's layering design were done right, though, it would work, because the implementation wouldn't know/care which configuration format was used; properly, `ENTRYPOINT foo` should turn into the exact same thing as `ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "foo"]`)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You're correct, `ENTRYPOINT ls "$@"` gets it working, although as you pointed out an extra argument is required

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, this has nothing to do with done right or wrong. It actually makes sense the way it is. This is because how calls to exec.Command work. It expects a command and an array of args. If we pass an array in the dockerfile the first item is the command and the rest is the args. But if you give a single string like this, the only way to run it is to wrap it in shell, if you want to avoid ambiguity.  https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#CommandContext

Comment: you have used it literally in your previous comment quote: *if Docker's layering design were done right, though*

Comment: @TheFool, correct, and I told you above what specific aspect of good software design I was referring to when I said "right". I'm not objecting to Docker's use of a shell; it's reasonable given the design constraints. In the hypothetical world where my suggestion didn't work, I would be objecting to Docker changing how it passes arguments through as a side effect of the user's choice of configuration syntax, because when it _does_ just append arguments to argv -- having identical runtime behavior no matter which config format is used -- the shell syntax suggested works properly.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, well. And I told you that I think it makes sense. Would love to see your implementation. If we talk about good design, we should rather mention that using a custom file format, the Dockerfile, was a poor decision. They could have used any number of existing config languages and would not need to maintain a parser and all that jazz.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250981/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-the-fool).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ENTRYPOINT string_here
```

...has Docker run:

```json
["sh", "-c", "string_here"]
```

The problem with this is that when you add more arguments, they're added as new elements on the argument vector, as in:

```json
["sh", "-c", "string_here", "arg1", "arg2", "arg3..."]
```

which means they're ignored, because `string_here`, when invoked as a script, doesn't look at what further arguments it's given.

Thus, you can use:

```
ENTRYPOINT string_here "$0" "$@"
```

where `"$@"` in shell expands to `"$1" "$2" "$3" ...`, and `$0` is the first argument following `-c` (which is typically the name of the script or executable, and used in error messages written by the shell itself).